# What is the third homotopy group of $SO(5)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to compute the $\pi_3(SO(5))$, but not getting any idea to compute it.

As in the case of first and second homotopy groups of $SO(5)$, which can easily be computed using the long exact sequence of homotopy groups. I know that $S^3$ covers $SO(3)$, and $S^3\times S^3$ covers $SO(4)$, but I don’t know whether we have any such covering for $SO(5)$ or not. Any help would be great.

Comment: There is a fibration sequence $SO_4\rightarrow SO_5\rightarrow S^5$. In general the group $Spin_n$ is a two-fold universal covering of $SO_n$. The exceptional isomorphisms give $Spin_3\cong S^3$, $Spin_4\cong S^3\times S^3$, $Spin_5\cong Sp_2$ and $Spin_6\cong SU_4$.

Comment: @Tyrone I think you want the base to be $S^4$, so the argument changes somewhat if you want to use $\text{Spin}_4$. But you can run a similar fibration sequence with your second exceptional isomorphism to get $\text{Sp}_1 \to \text{Spin}_5 \to S^7$ and compare to $\pi_3 \text{Sp}_1 = \pi_3 S^3 = \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMiller, for pointing out the mistake. The base of the fibration should, of course, be $S^4$. Remark that the the fibration you mention comes from the exceptional isomorphism $Spin_5\cong Sp_2$.

Answer (score 5):

First note that $SO(n)$ has double cover $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$, so for $i > 1$, we have $\pi_i(SO(n)) \cong \pi_i(\operatorname{Spin}(n))$. For small values of $n$, there are exceptional isomorphisms:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Spin}(1) &\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\\
\operatorname{Spin}(2) &\cong U(1)\\
\operatorname{Spin}(3) &\cong SU(2) \cong Sp(1)\\
\operatorname{Spin}(4) &\cong SU(2)\times SU(2) \cong Sp(1)\times Sp(1)\\
\operatorname{Spin}(5) &\cong Sp(2)\\
\operatorname{Spin}(6) &\cong SU(4).
\end{align*}

Therefore $\pi_3(SO(5)) \cong \pi_3(\operatorname{Spin}(5)) \cong \pi_3(Sp(2))$.

The long exact sequence in homotopy applied to the fibration $Sp(1) \to Sp(2) \to S^7$ shows that $\pi_3(Sp(2)) \cong \pi_3(Sp(1))$. As $Sp(1)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$, we see that $\pi_3(Sp(2)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $\pi_3(SO(5)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

More generally, $\pi_3(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for any simple Lie group $G$. This was shown by Bott in *An application of the Morse theory to the topology of Lie-groups*.

Comment: Thanks as it sounds ok.